# How to programmatically determine time interval state

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I have a problem where I need to do something at certain intervals over a certain amount of times.  For example over 5 minutes I want to repeat between state 1 and state 2 (each with their own specified amount of time)  then repeat until the full 5 minutes has elapsed.

For example over 5 minutes I'd like state 1 to be 40 sec and state 2 to be 20 seconds.

I'd appreciate either pseudo code, C#, VB, C++, or C code for determining the current state is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo-code:

```
state1Time = 40;
state2Time = 20;
duration = 300;

while (duration > 0 && duration > state1Time)
{
    if (duration >= state1Time)
    {
        changeState(1);
        sleep(state1Time);
    }
    duration -= state1Time;
    if (duration >= state2Time)
    {
        changeState(2);
        sleep(state2Time);
    }
    duration -= state2Time;
}

changeState(none);
```